# Adding HttpHandler to MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httphandler

I have an MVC4 application to which I added an `HttpHandler`:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="Files" verb="*" type="MyHttpHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

I also ignored the relevant path in `RegisterRoutes` so that the requests to "Files" are not handled by MVC:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Files/{*pathInfo}");
```

The problem is that the `MyHttpHandler` is invoked only for requests to "Files", not for any of its children or sub-folders.

I've tried using the `<location>` element, but getting that to work means that you will be hard coding the application's virtual path in the "path" attribute (e.g., `<location path='MyApp\Files'>`).

What is the correct method to use to allow all requests for "Files" and any of its sub-folders (and sub-folders of those folder, etc) to get routed to `MyHttpHandler`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scratch that...`<location>` seems to work OK.  Though, you need both the `<web>` and `<webServer>` entries to ensure that it works for both IIS and the Visual Studio Development Server.  For example:

```
<location path="Files">`
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="MyHandler" path="*" verb="*" type="MyHttpHandler" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="*" verb="*" type="MyHttpHandler" />
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
</location>
```